# In a Jenkinsfile, how to access a variable that is declared within a sh step?

Tags: bash, variables, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sh

Say I have a Jenkinsfile. Within that Jenkinsfile, is the following sh step:

```
sh "myScript.sh"
```

Within myScript.sh, the following variable is declared:

```
MY_VARIABLE="This is my variable"
```

How can I access MY_VARIABLE, which is declared in myScript.sh, from my Jenkinsfile?

Comment: You cannot access variables declared inside a shell script in your Jenkinsfile. Other way is possible and recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import the variable defined in your script into the current shell, you can use the `source` command (see [explanation on SU](https://superuser.com/a/46146/954154)):

```
# Either via command
source myScript.sh
# Or via built-in synonym
. myScript.sh
```

Supposing your script does not output anything, you can then instead output the variable to fetch it in Jenkins:

```groovy
def myVar = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '. myScript.sh && echo $MY_VARIABLE')
```

If indeed outputs comes from your script, you can fetch the last output either per shell:

```
(. myScript.sh && echo $MY_VARIABLE) | tail -n1
```

or via Groovy:

```groovy
def out = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '. myScript.sh && echo $MY_VARIABLE')
def myVar = out.tokenize('\n')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The bash variable declared in .sh file is ending with the pipeline step: `sh` complete.

But you can make you .sh to generate a properties file, then use pipeline step: [readProperties](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) to read the file into object for accessing.

```
// myScript.sh
...

echo MY_VARIABLE=This is my variable > vars.properties


// pipeline 
sh 'myScript.sh'
def props = readProperties file: 'vars.properties'
echo props.MY_VARIABLE
```